# Customer feedback builder web application

Tags: web-apps, survey

I'm looking for a web application that can be used to build and customize "customer feedback" pages, like this one:

[image: "How would you rate the quality our service?"]

Requirements:

- possibly free
- should run on a standard stack, for example LAMP
- pages should be customizable, for example with JavaScript events, and so on

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a tool such as Zendesk, then they should have built in customer satisfaction features that may be worth trying. If not suitable, then there may be a plugin that they can offer.

FreshDesk is another alternative and has a free level too, but i'm not sure if they have the satisfaction features.